# Atualizar dados Power Query e Copiar Valores pelo VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, powerquery

Preciso atualizar algumas células na minha planilha assim que uma atualização na tabela da Power Query é feita, mas as células só atualizam a segunda vez que eu executo o código.

```
Sub AtualizarDadosPowerQuery()
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Consulta - Tabela3").Refresh
    Sheets("Relatorio").Range("B12").Value = Sheets("CNPJ").Range("D2").Value
    Sheets("Relatorio").Range("T12").Value = Sheets("CNPJ").Range("P2").Value
    Sheets("Relatorio").Range("B15").Value = Sheets("CNPJ").Range("S2").Value
End Sub
```

A aba `"Relatorio"` é a aba em que os valores devem ir e não atualiza de primeira.
A aba `"CNPJ"` é a aba em que os valores precisam ser buscados, ela sim atualiza de primeira.

Answer (score 1):

É necessário definir que o `.Refresh` não ocorra em modo background (atualização em segundo plano).

> mas as células só atualizam a segunda vez que eu rodo o código

Considerando que a atualização em background está ativada, o código dispara o `.Refresh` e faz a cópia das células predefinidas antes de ter concluído a atualização.
Por isso que, ao executar o código pela segunda vez, os dados estão sendo copiados corretamente, pois agora ele já concluiu o primeiro `.Refresh` e está com os dados atualizados para fazer a cópia. Mas é provável que ele ainda esteja executando a segunda solicitação de `.Refresh`, mas não se percebe o "erro" dessa vez.

**Opção 01:**
Desative a atualização em background (atualização em segundo plano), em Consulta/Propriedades/Uso/Controle de Atualização. Telas e detalhes nos links abaixo, de respostas já existentes.

**Opção 02:**
Tempo de atualização é bem relativo, depende de cada máquina, arquivo, conexão etc. Avalie com atenção se é aplicável no seu caso. É possível definir um atraso para o VBA, entre o `.Refresh` e as próximas linhas, que copiam os valores. O código abaixo deixa um intervalo de 5 segundos:

```
Sub AtualizarDadosPowerQuery()
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Consulta - Tabela3").Refresh

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    Sheets("Relatorio").Range("B12").Value = Sheets("CNPJ").Range("D2").Value
    Sheets("Relatorio").Range("T12").Value = Sheets("CNPJ").Range("P2").Value
    Sheets("Relatorio").Range("B15").Value = Sheets("CNPJ").Range("S2").Value
End Sub
```

Veja também:

- [VBA Wait for refresh of power query to execute next line of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376784/vba-wait-for-refresh-of-power-query-to-execute-next-line-of-code)
- [How to wait for a Power Query refresh to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000659/how-to-wait-for-a-power-query-refresh-to-finish)
- [Waiting for
  query to finish before continuing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064762/waiting-for-query-to-finish-before-continuing)
- [How to pause for specific amount of time? (Excel/VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544526/how-to-pause-for-specific-amount-of-time-excel-vba)

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou!

Answer (score -3):

Blz pessoal!
Aproveitei a dica do amigo acima e personalizei o código.
Segue abaixo:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim i As Long
Dim myTitle As String, MyMsg As String, Response As String

myTitle = "Atualizacao da Query"
MyMsg = "Voce deseja atualizar a Query?"
Response = MsgBox(MyMsg, vbExclamation + vbYesNoCancel, myTitle)

'Perguntar ao usuario se quer atualizar a consulta
Select Case Response
    Case Is = vbYes
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")) 'Aguardar 5 segundos
        For i = 1 To 3 'So utilizo 3 conexoes PowerQuey
            ThisWorkbook.Connections(i).Refresh 'Percorre consultas e atualiza
        Next
    Case Is = vbNo
        ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False 'Fecha sem salvar
    Case Is = vbCancel
        Exit Sub
End Select

End Sub
```